# Simulink executable is not reading .mat files

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink model wihich reads some data from a .mat file using a "From File" block. For ilustration's sake I created the following simple system which has the same problem I'm experiencing with my original model:
[image]

I need to generate a C code to run the model on another PC that does not have MATLAB. I generated the code and compiled it to validate it and I noticed that the executable is not reading the .mat file. No matter what signal I put on the file, the executable runs the model using the signal available at the moment of the compilation. I even erased the .mat file and the executable ran normally. Why is this happening? it is supposed that the "From File" block is there to read a .mat file, but it is not fulfilling its purpose.

NOTE: I am using MATLAB R2012b and Simulink version 8.0. I am using the Embedded Coder target (ert.tlc) for the code generation. I tried using the Rapid Simulation target (rsim.tlc) and the executable worked properly, however the execution time was higher. So I want to find a way to use the Embedded Coder target to have a lower execution time.

Comment: There's no in-built way to get the ert target to read from a .mat file -- that's not what it's designed for.  The work around would be to write an S-Function that calls the appropriate mex functions to read a .mat file and include that in your built code, which would also require writing a tlc file.  But, I would highlight that the speed comparison you mention is invalid.  You are comparing ert using hard coded inputs, to rsim using file read functionality.  You'll probably find that ert modified to also do file reading is also slower.

Comment: It seems strange to me that ERT target does not support file reading, as there are code generation requirements for using the "From File" block with the ERT target in the documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromfile.html

Comment: Why not just stating in the documentation that ERT target does not support file reading and hence does not support the "From File" block?

Comment: It does support the From File block, it just hard codes the data used in the file specified at compile time.

Comment: That is no different from the "From Workspace" block, in that case I will have to stick with the RSIM target. By the way, the code generated with the RSIM target can be compiled in other PCs?